# Do we have to implement syspolicy_purge_history job in case of azure database, as there is no msdb

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, azure

I migrated from sql server to Azure db. While migrating I found a job named syspolicy_purge_history (sp_syspolicy_purge_history), do I also need to implement it on Azure db. As I found the syspolicy_purge_history job is targeting msdb, but I could not found msdb on Azure. A guidance will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

[sp_syspolicy_purge_history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-syspolicy-purge-history-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is just a system procedure used to cleanup old logged records for when a Policy runs in SQL Server, from the `msdb` database specifically (which is where those logs are stored).

Since `msdb` isn't available in Azure DB, this is not relevant there and you should have no concern for it. In fact, the docs I linked above say "*Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions)*", meaning it's only applicable in SQL Server, and not other database implementations like Azure DB.